# How to return to main menu when user click Letter "M"?

Tags: java

How to return to main menu upon user enter letter "M". It would direct them to main menu page?

I tried using while(!inChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("M")); but it does not work. Any idea what went wrong ?

public static void searchByCountry() {

```
    int n, i, j, x;

    n = (uniqueCountries.length)-1;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {

        for(j=i+1; j<n;) {

            if(uniqueCountries[i]==uniqueCountries[j]) {

                for(x=j; x<n; x++) {

                    uniqueCountries[x] = uniqueCountries[x+1];
                } 

                n--;

            } 

            else {

                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    String msg = "";
    msg = "";

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {

        String allUniqueCountries = uniqueCountries[i];

        msg += (i+1) + ". " + allUniqueCountries +" "+ "\n";       
    }
```

String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter country number\n" + msg);

```
    int countryChoice = Integer.parseInt(input);

    String result = "";

    int count = 1;

    if(countryChoice == 1) {



        for(i=0; i<3; i++) {



        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Search result: " + count + "\n" 
        + "=======================\n" 
        + "Country: " + country[i] + "\n" 
        + "Month: " + travelmonth[i] + "\n" 
        + "Description: " + description[i] + "\n" 
        + "Price: $" + price[i] + "\n" + "=======================\n" 
        + "Enter M to return to main menu");
        count++;         

        }

    }

    //else if
    if (countryChoice == 2) {

        for(i=3; i<5; i++) {

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Search result: " + count + "\n" 
        + "=======================\n" 
        + "Country: " + country[i] + "\n" 
        + "Month: " + travelmonth[i] + "\n" 
        + "Description: " + description[i] + "\n" 
        + "Price: $" + price[i] + "\n" 
        + "=======================\n" 
        + "Enter M to return to main menu");
        count++;

        }

    }
```

else if(countryChoice == 3){

```
        for(i=5; i<8; i++) {

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Search result: " + count + "\n" 
        + "=======================\n" 
        + "Country: " + country[i] + "\n" 
        + "Month: " + travelmonth[i] + "\n" 
        + "Description: " + description[i] + "\n" 
        + "Price: $" + price[i] + "\n" 
        + "=======================\n" 
        + "Enter M to return to main menu");
        count++;

        }
    }

    while(!inChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("M"));
}
```

}

Comment: Edit your post to add additional code/content.

Comment: @Zachary edited

Comment: Where is inChoice and the while(...) you mentioned wasn't working? Is the content you posted relevant? When you take an input from the user, that would be the best point to check if it is M.

Comment: @Zachary I took it out cause its not working.

Comment: Where do you have the input for the character, how is the input formatted? Are you able to provide that code and remove any code irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: @Zachary the user has to enter "M" in order to return main menu as per what my assignment require

Comment: @Zachary added in the additional code

Comment: All the code and still we do not see what is source of `inChoice`. Should `countryChoice` be tested instead?

Answer (score 0):

You will actually need to take a new input and then check if it matches "M". The way you have presented the question makes it difficult to tell how you are actually managing input. It uses a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to take a users input.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("M")) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Further, it would be bad practice to poll within a functional method like this would do. You could call a method such as waitForM() which is solely dedicated to do this after you call the searchByCountry() method in your main body. Something like this would handle a lot better.

```
    /* Scanner used to read input from console */
    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    /* Main entry point to program */
    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {
        String input = "";
        /* Keep getting input until it is "exit", then finish */
        while (!(input = getInput()).equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
            System.out.println("Enter desired input. Type exit to exit");
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("search")) {
                SearchByCountry();
            }
            WaitForM();
        }
    }

    public static void SearchByCountry() {
        /* Do Stuff */
    }

    /* Method to wait for M Input */
    public static void WaitForM() {
        System.out.println("Enter M to return to Menu");
        String input = "";
        while (!(input = getInput()).equalsIgnoreCase("M")) {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: whats the 'sc' ?

Comment: Missed that sorry. It's a scanner looking for input.